# C# Executing several methods at the same time, Method Concurrency

Tags: c#, concurrency

This is my first question.
I'm building a simple program for my c# class to simulate a slot machine and i'm emulating the columns? spinning effect with this bit of code

```
 static void EfeitoJackpot()
        {
            string[] simbolos = new string[10] { "!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "=", "@", "~", "»", "«" };
            Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 1);
            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {

                Console.Write(simbolos[i % 10] + "\b");


                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(80); // velocidade

            }
        }
```

Now, my problem is that I want to display this  happening 3x times concurrently. I've been reading about MultiThreading and Parallel Looping but after much effort I'm still stuck.

To summarize I want this to happen

```
              ** [ spinning ]    [ spinning ]    [ spinning ] **
```

And this is what is happening

```
             ** [ spinning ] ..(method finishes executing)... [spinning] and so forth
```

Comment: Don't be so literal. Just because there are three spindles spinning does not mean you need three threads. You would only need three threads if you have a CPU-bound problem, which this is not-- it is mostly about waiting, then picking a random number. I would recommend you solve this with a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are building a "simple program," you don't need multithreading for this as it overcomplicates things. You can just use a looping structure. Something like this:

```
const int MAX = 10;
string[] simbolos = new string[MAX] { "!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "=", "@", "~", "»", "«" };

// Start with some random positions for each column.
Random r = new Random();
int column1Index = r.Next(MAX);
int column2Index = r.Next(MAX);
int column3Index = r.Next(MAX);

// Track overall status, and status of each column.
bool keepSpinning = true;
bool spin1 = true, spin2 = true, spin3 = true;

while (keepSpinning)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{simbolos[column1Index]} {simbolos[column2Index]} {simbolos[column3Index]}");

    if (spin1)
    {
        column1Index = column1Index < MAX - 1 ? column1Index + 1 : 0;
        spin1 = SomethingToDetermineIfColumnShouldKeepSpinning(1);
    }

    if (spin2)
    {
        column2Index = column2Index < MAX - 1 ? column2Index + 1 : 0;
        spin2 = SomethingToDetermineIfColumnShouldKeepSpinning(2);
    }

    if (spin3)
    {
        column3Index = column3Index < MAX - 1 ? column3Index + 1 : 0; 
        spin3 = SomethingToDetermineIfColumnShouldKeepSpinning(3);
    }
}
```